# How to optimize camera property changes in three.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am basically using a modified version of the random points WebGL three.js demo that can be found here: 
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_random

Now I added a scroll event listener to change the fov and position of the camera when scrolling down, but because of the way cameras work in three.js, I have to update the camera projection matrix in every frame and this is very bad for the performance as you can see in the following examples:

[Although it's quite smooth in firefox](https://gfycat.com/FamiliarSnivelingGermanshepherd)

[it is very choppy on other browser such as Safari or Chrome.](https://gfycat.com/BaggyForthrightKingsnake)

Comment: The original three.js example runs great in Safari and Chrome. Share your code?

Comment: Well the particle movement runs great it's just the scroll transition that doesn't run well.

You can have a look @ http://rotgruenblau.ch/demo/index.html

I am currently thinking of scroll transition animations that don't involve the camera.

Comment: Runs spiffy on El Capitan, with Intel Iris Pro, Chrome browser. In Chrome setting, "System," Check that "use hardware acceleration when available" is checked. Mine was by default. ALso when using Safari and Chrome be sure you're not also using Photoshop, After Effects, or other heavy GPU enabled software.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you were right, I did have resource intensive stuff open...haha. I'm just worried that it wouldn't perform as great on lower end machines. Personally I'm using a mid 13 macbook air with an Intel HD 6000.

Comment: You can track FPS easily with three.js. Reduce the number of sprites per FPS. 30 fps *10 for example would be 300 sprites. 12 fps would be 120.

Comment: How did you decide that the FOV change is a performance bottle neck? It should not affect things much if at all, it's one matrix operation, and gets set for the shaders anyway. Something else is an issue here, it would be good to see your code.